# How to Dynamically Change Text Based on User Input

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, lwc-dom, dom, lightning-layouts

I am fairly new to SF, and I am only moderately well-versed in JS in general. I am attempting to create a LWC that will display a URL based on user input. This URL will eventually be used to retrieve an iFrame and display it, however for now, I only need it to display a string with the URL. The problem I am coming across is that the URLs are created when the page loads, so all the values that I attempted to construct the URL with dynamically are static.

I would like to be able to either add a refresh button that changes the URL, or have the URL change in real-time. So far, I have coded in the refresh button but I'm not sure where to go from here. Extensive googling has turned up nothing for what must surely be a relatively simple answer.

Here is my JS:

```
import {
    LightningElement,
    api,
    track
} from 'lwc';


export default class ReportComponent extends LightningElement {

    // Variables 
    @track salesNum = null;
    @track customerNum = null;
    @track startDate = null;
    @track endDate = null;
    @track orderURL;
    @track averageURL;


    // Event Handlers

    handleSales(event) {
        this.salesNum = event.target.value;
        console.log('Current SalesNum: ' + event.target.value);
    }

    handleCustomer(event) {
        this.customerNum = event.target.value;
        console.log('Current CustomerNum: ' + event.target.value);
    }

    handleStart(event) {
        this.startDate = event.target.value;
        console.log('Current value of Start Date: ' + event.target.value);
    }

    handleEnd(event) {
        this.endDate = event.target.value;
        console.log('Current value of End Date: ' + event.target.value);
    }

    handleOrderSummary(event) {
        this.orderURL = event.target.value;
        console.log('Current value Order URL: ' + event.target.value);
    }

    handleAverageSummary(event) {
        this.averageURL = event.target.value;
        console.log('Current value averageURL: ' + event.target.value);
    }

    // Order Summary Report

    orderURL = 'https://someReportViewer.&salesforce_salesman_number=' + this.salesNum + 'salesforce_customer_number=' + this.customerNum + '&ship_date_begin=1/1/' + this.startDate + '&ship_date_end=' + this.endDate;

    // Average Selling Price Report

    averageURL = 'https://someReportViewer/averagesellingprice&salesforce_salesman_number=' + this.salesNum + 'salesforce_customer_number=' + this.customerNum + '&ship_date_begin=1/1/' + this.startDate + '&ship_date_end=' + this.endDate;


    get getAverageURL() {
        if (this)
            return this.averageURL;
        else
            return null;
    }

    get getOrderURL() {
        if (this)
            return this.orderURL;
        else
            return null;
    }

    refreshComponent(event){
        eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
    }


}
```

And the HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title='REPORT GENERATOR'>
        <lightning-layout>
            <lightning-layout-item class="numberBox" size="5" medium-device-size="5" padding="around-small">
                <lightning-input text="Number..." label="Salesmen Number" onchange={handleSales}>
                </lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item class="numberBox" size="5" medium-device-size="5" padding="around-small">
                <lightning-input text="Number..." label="Customer Number" onchange={handleCustomer}>
                </lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout>
            <div class="row">
                <h2 class="header">Start Date</h2>
                <lightning-input class="numberBox" type="date" name="startDate" label="Enter a date..." onchange={handleStart}>
                </lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <h2 class="header">End Date</h2>
                <lightning-input class="numberBox" type="date" name="endDate" label="Enter a date..." onchange={handleEnd}>
                </lightning-input>
            </div>
        </lightning-layout>
        
</lightning-card>
           <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-card title="Order Summary:" onchange={handleOrderSummary} >
          {getOrderURL}
        <lightning-button label="Get Report..." onclick={refreshComponenet}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-card>
        </lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-card  title="Average Selling Price:" onchange={handleAverageSummary} >
            {getAverageURL}
            <lightning-button label="Get Report..." onclick={refreshComponenet}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-card>
        </lightning-layout> 

</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make this properties as `getter` like this:

```
    // Order Summary Report

  get orderURL() {
   return 'https://someReportViewer.&salesforce_salesman_number=' + this.salesNum + 'salesforce_customer_number=' + this.customerNum + '&ship_date_begin=1/1/' + this.startDate + '&ship_date_end=' + this.endDate;
  }

    // Average Selling Price Report

  get averageURL() { 
    return 'https://someReportViewer/averagesellingprice&salesforce_salesman_number=' + this.salesNum + 'salesforce_customer_number=' + this.customerNum + '&ship_date_begin=1/1/' + this.startDate + '&ship_date_end=' + this.endDate;
  }
```

this will ensure that your URL values are recalculated dynamically. Or you can set new values in `renderedCallback`

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.

Comment: your welcome, good luck in your LWC journey